# Amazon EMR terminateJobFlows for requests with more than maximum clusters that can be terminated

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm using AWSElasticMapReduceJavaClient-1.11.x, and the maximum clusters that EMR can terminate at one time is 10. How would I go about terminating a request with let's say 100 clusters all in one `terminateJobFlows` call? I'm implementing the `AmazonElasticMapReduce` interface so this method needs to be overridden and return a `TerminateJobFlowsResult`. This is unfortunately not backwards compatible with version 1.10 as `terminateJobFlows` was a void method, but it now returns a result.

```
@Override
public TerminateJobFlowsResult terminateJobFlows(TerminateJobFlowsRequest request) {
  List<List<String>> distributedClusterIds = Lists.partition(request.getJobFlowIds(), 10);

  distributedClusterIds.stream()
                .map(TerminateJobFlowsRequest::new)
                .forEach(request -> {
                    emrClient.terminateJobFlows(request); // returns a TerminateJobFlowsResult
                    // How to return each result somehow??
                });

}
```

Comment: On second thought, I don't really think this is possible..I'm thinking about doing the partitioning step outside of this method (where this method is called), and just call this interface method X times (in this case 10 times for 100 clusters)

Answer (score 0):

The [TerminateJobFlowsResult](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.11.519/aws-java-sdk-emr/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/model/TerminateJobFlowsResult.java) object contains no content and is functionally equivalent to the `void` return in previous SDK versions. This means you can return any of the instances you receive indiscriminately or simply create a new one yourself and return it at the end to satisfy the interface contract.